# mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds and Premature end of script headers: index.php

Tags: timeout, plesk, mod-fcgid

One of my website clients had issues while placing orders.
When I checked my error log I could see this :

```
[warn]  mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds, referer: https://myDomain/cart
[error] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: https://myDomain/cart
```

What does this error mean? What should I do to eliminate this error? Are there any settings to be changed in Plesk Control panel? will it be solved if I change 'max_execution_time' in 'Php settings' to 3600?

I am using Plesk 12.0.18, CentOS 5.11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error means that website code in `index.php` file fails to be executed in the time limit, which set for Apache FastCGI module and/or PHP.

- Most likely, there is an error in the `index.php`, which makes it inoperable at all. In this case, you should increase the PHP error reporting level in **Plesk > Domains > example.com > PHP Settings** and review the script itself.
- Less likely that script is meant to take a long time to execute. In this case, you may simply increase timeout via Plesk. To set 120 seconds instead of default 45, do the following:

1. Set `max_execution_time` to `120` in **Plesk > Domains > example.com > PHP settings**.

2. Increase `FastCGI timeout` by adding the following Apache dirctives in **Plesk > Domains > example.com > Apache & Nginx settings > Additional Apache directives**:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c> 
FcgidIOTimeout 120 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi.. Can you help me with this error "

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: Hi. I have increased max_input_vars  to 10000. Will it cause any further problems?